# Checkbox in Django - What is best practice?

Tags: django

I am aware that on [djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.NullBooleanField) there is a explanation that you should use NullBooleanField for a checkbox in Django, however, I am wondering if it would be better to use something like this?

```
models.CharField(null=True, choices=(('Y','YES'),))
```

Then null would just evaluate to not checked and yes would evaluate to checked. This seems to make more sense to me rather than NullBooleanField where you would have essentially

```
models.CharField(null=True, choices=(('1','UNKNOWN'),('2','YES'),('3','NO'),))
```

my interpretation  of NullBooleanField could be (and probably is) incorrect, but when I render a crispy forms, it gave me a `select` box, so wouldn't it be represented this way in the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your logic only requires True/False, and not Null, then it would be better to use a `BooleanField` instead of a `NullBooleanField`, with `default=False`.

A `NullBooleanField` is indeed essentially a field with Yes/No/Unknown choices.

Note that a `CharField` never saves `NULL` but always an empty string, so `null=True` would have no effect on a `CharField`.

Comment: Oh, alright. I'll probably just scrap NullBooleanField and use BooleanField then, Thanks!